# Joining 3 tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-match-all, relational-division

I am trying to solve this problem for quite some time and the output is wrong. Can anyone help me with this? I am using mysql, so full join doesnt work. Thank yyou

3 tables:

```
Frequents (attributes: drinker, bar, times_a_week),
Likes (attributes: drinker, beer),
Serves (attributes: bar, beer, price),
```

The question ask for all the drinkers who frequent "every" bar which serve some beers they like

My answer looks like this:

```
SELECT drinker 
FROM frequents 
WHERE drinker NOT IN (SELECT f.drinker FROM frequents f 
                  JOIN likes l ON f.drinker=l.drinker
                  LEFT JOIN serves s ON l.beer=s.beer
                  AND s.bar=f.bar
                  WHERE s.bar IS NULL)
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: @ypercube: nice edit. I'm not sure I was aware of the `relational-division` tag!

Comment: @onedaywhen: I've voted for the 2 tags to be merged (sql-match-all and relational-division)

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
select * 
from Frequents
where bar in (select bar from Serves  S join Likes  L on S.beer=l.beer)
```

if it doesn't work, can you post some example of your data?